# Como atribuir um valor nulo para uma variável de entrada, caso o usuário deixe o campo em branco ou digite zero?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, validação, stored-procedures

O contexto no qual surgiu o problema é o seguinte:

Tenho um procedimento armazenado que realiza o cadastro de determinados valores em uma tabela do meu banco de dados.

Nesse procedimento defini todas as variáveis como de entrada, logo meu usuário deve inserir algum tipo de valor, porém nem todos os campos devem ser obrigatoriamente preenchidos, apenas o campo que preenche minha coluna que é uma chave estrangeira.

Os campos que não possuem obrigatoriedade de preenchimento possuo a possibilidade de orientar o usuário a inserir "zeros" ou automatizar minha aplicação e inserir um valor nulo caso meu usuário digite zero ou deixe o campo em branco, eu optei pela segunda opção, já que o armazenamento de "zeros" utiliza espaço em meu servidor.

Ao aplicar a validação necessária para a segunda opção, meu procedimento esbarra em erros o usuário digitando zero ou deixando o campo em branco.

**Quando o usuário insere "zero" aparece a mensagem de erro 1054.**

**Quando deixa o campo em branco aparece a mensagem de erro 1064.**

**A validação que estou utilizando é a seguinte:**

---

`p_n_cliente` é uma variável de entrada.

`if (p_n_cliente = none or '0') then do p_n_cliente = null; end if;`

Comment: Por acaso não seria: `if (p_n_cliente = none or p_n_cliente = '0') then do p_n_cliente = null; end if;`? (supondo que `none` seja uma variável anteriormente definida)

Comment: Tentei dessa forma também, porém não obtive o resultado esperado. Quando o usuário digitou "zero" ele cadastrou "zero" e não "nulo", e ao deixar o campo em branco ele deu erro.

Comment: E qual o tipo de dado da variável `p_n_cliente`? Como é feita a leitura do valor digitado? Já pensou em utilizar a função `NULLIF`?

Comment: Bom, o dado que entra nessa variável é do tipo `INT`, nesse formulário de cadastro possuo outros tipos de variáveis, `FLOAT` e `DATE`. Sobre a leitura do valor digitado eu não sei te explicar como isso é feito, eu estou utilizando o próprio MySQL pra validar meus procedimentos, então eu executo o procedimento e abre a janela pra inserir os valores. Não conheço essa função, vou tentar usá-la.

Comment: Bom, fiz uma alteração na minha validação e ficou da seguinte forma: ```if (p_n_cliente = '' or p_n_cliente = '0') 
then set p_n_cliente = null; end if;```. Dessa maneira a validação esta cadastrando ```NULL``` quando é inserido ```0``` , porém ainda da erro quando o campo é deixado em branco.